# Import the same package into multiple modules of a local package

Tags: python, import, package

I have a local 'models' package for a Flask app I'm writing, where each model class lives in its own .py file and the 'models' dir has a (currently empty, apart from version info) `__init__.py` file so I can import it.
This setup works fine, but each module currently imports sqlite3 to do database operations. **Is there a way to use a single import statement, for example in `__init__.py`, instead of requiring a statement in each individual module?**

I created a very simple local package to see if I could make it work myself, but this did not work:

```
package-test/
    testpkg/
        __init__.py
        one.py
```

where `__init__.py` contains `from datetime import date as dt` and `one.py` contains:

```
def sayDate():
    return dt.today()
```

When I run the REPL from the package-test dir I can `from testpkg import one` no problem, but running `one.sayDate()` returns `name 'dt' is not defined`.

Keeping it more general, for example doing `import datetime` in `__init__.py` and saying `return datetime.date.today()` in the module's function definition, returns `name 'datetime' is not defined` instead.

Or is there a better way altogether to prevent having to import the same thing in multiple modules?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't have to worry about importing one module multiple times. Imported modules are cached in `sys.modules` and the actual process of importing `sqlite3` will occur only once.

Comment: I didn't know, but did assume that Python would be clever enough to do that. It would still be great to know if it's possible to use a single import statement somewhere that applies to each module in the package.